# apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"

Tags: firefox, snap, dbus, apparmor

My syslog is getting many messages like this:

```
dbus-daemon[1311]: message repeated 12 times: [ apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.30" pid=33590 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1646 peer_label="unconfined"]
```

kern.log also contains this:

```
kernel: [16957.155886] audit: type=1107 audit(1697596358.271:348): pid=823 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.410" pid=33590 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=34265 peer_label="unconfined"
kernel: [16957.155886]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

It all seems related to Firefox.
I have searched but can't find an answer.

My configuration:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mksmith-laptop 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.
Mitch

Comment: Do you happen to have any issues with continuous GPE interrupts too? I'm seeing a lot of what you've reported above and I'm also having constant ACPI issues. Not sure if they are related, though.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. No, I'm not seeing anything relating to GPE interrupts.